# \uppercase not working with dynamic text

Tags: macros

I've got some layout that I'm trying to make into something that can be parameterized with dynamic text:

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{spotcolor}{cmyk}{.40,0,.70,0}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [ white, fill=spotcolor, rounded corners=4pt, inner sep=4pt, font=\sffamily] at  (-1.1in,-.7in){\tiny\uppercase { starter }};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However when I make the label dynamic text using a macro...

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{spotcolor}{cmyk}{.40,0,.70,0}
\newcommand{\level}{starter}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [ white, fill=spotcolor, rounded corners=4pt, inner sep=4pt, font=\sffamily] at  (-1.1in,-.7in){\tiny\uppercase { \level }};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The \uppercase command seems to have no effect

[image]

Comment: Don't use `\uppercase` but `\MakeUppercase`, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{spotcolor}{cmyk}{.40,0,.70,0}
\newcommand\level{starter}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [ white, fill=spotcolor, rounded corners=4pt, inner sep=4pt, font=\sffamily] at (-1.1in,-.7in){\tiny\MakeUppercase { \level }};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's weird... a question marked as a duplicate (i.e., closed) that has an answer *after* it was closed.

Comment: @Werner: Sorry, I didn't see it. I guess we were clicking at the same time. Shall I delete it?

Comment: Nah, keep it. It is just strange as the system typically doesn't accept answers *after* a question is closed. However, yours seemed to slip through for some reason.

Comment: Sorry to bother you both.  I saw it was a duplicate right after I posted it and tried to comment about that, but not sure that went through either.   Thanks for the help.  I really appreciate everyone on this site while I'm learning LaTeX.